# deploy using GitHub action

Tags: reactjs, github-actions

while deploying react app using surge through github action i got following error

[image]

```
Run surge ./build https://reactapp-saim.surge.sh --token ***
   Running as email@gmail.com (Student)
   Aborted - No such file or directory: ./build
```

image on my git action. where is the error?

[image]

Comment: Git does not have actions. Git*Hub* provide things called actions. Please don't use images of text where plain text will do: your low contrast images are too difficult for me to read. See [ask].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question